# Как сделать в jqery , чтобы перетаскиваемый элемент фиксировался и больше не перетаскивался

Tags: jquery

Доброе утро.В своем приложение я решил использовать библиотеку JQERY ,а именно draggable и droppable. В документации я нашел такой пример кода.

В общем, у меня не получается сделать так, чтобы перетаскиваемый элемент фиксировался на новом месте.Нужна помощь.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
  #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>
 
<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Да, чтобы фиксировался на новом месте

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Написано же, "фиксировался и больше не перетаскивался". Pavel После перемещения убрать обработчик "двигания" myObject.draggable( 'disable' ) Но не стоит забывать, что переместить могут неточно, случайно и т.л. Поэтому желательно сделать кнопку с возможностью восстановления этой возможности: myObject.draggable( 'enable' )

Comment: @Zombotron а, не проснулся ещё)